# Publishing items in child publications

Tags: 2013, publishing, blueprint

In order to publish item in child publication, publication target needs to be available in parent publication.

The challenge is, I don't want to publish the item from parent publication.

How can this be avoided?

First thing that comes to mind is event system, to remove item from the publish transaction. OK, if there is nothing better, I will go along.

Second thing, remove parent publication from child's publication target, create a new publication target for the parent and set same target type. Problem with this approach is that I can not have publication target without destination, so I have to deploy parent items somewhere...

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to consider using the **Child Publications Only Resolver** eXtension from the SDL Tridion World site that was developed by Bart: http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/childpublicationsonlyresolver.aspx

You still enable the Publishing Target for the parent, but the parent's items are removed using a Custom Resolver.

Comment: Good stuff. Tnx @Jonathan

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad it helped!

Comment: My [post](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/no-faking-publish-from-a-parent-publication-without-faking-a-publication-target) covered the setting that lets you publish from the parent without faking the destination. Be sure to see the comments on how Will Price added a bit more to Bart's resolver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question is very clear, but here my thoughts:

If you only want to publish from the child, go to the child publication and publish the child item(s). If your problem is that you need a publication target on the parent (so it is available in the children) and you don't want to publish anything on the parent, simply use permissions and remove "publishing" rights on the parent publication.

[image]